# Macbook charging but not really charging

Tags: startup, battery

My macbook's charging indicator light shows that it's charging (the light is orange) but it's not really charging because it's been always orange for the past 8 hours. At the moment, my battery is completely drained, thus, can't turn on the computer. I am not sure if the problem is the charger itself or if it's the computer. What should I do?

***edit***

My computer's battery was old  and i was already getting warnings that i needed to replace the battery soon. However, i could still have 3 hours off my battery after a full recharge

Comment: the battery is gone best to replace it.

Comment: Have you had any warnings about the battery prior to this?

Comment: Yes. It said that I needed to replace the battery soon

Comment: Also duplicates:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254180/119271 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387400/119271, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386557/119271

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind support. I will take it to Apple support for a closer inspection